# Write temporary files from Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Can I write to the container's local filesystem from a Google Cloud Function? AWS Lambda allows writing to /tmp:

> **Q: What if I need scratch space on disk for my AWS Lambda function?**
>   Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in
>   its own /tmp directory.

Is there something equivalent in GCF?

Comment: just remember...if you are writing to a dir called "tmp" you use ./tmp/ for local development and /tmp/ when you publish to gcp.

Comment: you might be tempted to create a var to switch easily - good idea! - just don't call it process.env.TMP on windows because you prob already have that as a windows env var.  lesson learned the hard way

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, the whole filesystem is writeable and mapped to memory. From https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system:

> The filesystem itself is entirely writeable (except for files used by the underlying OS) and is stored within the Cloud Functions instance's memory.

Comment: Is there any way to deploy files into this tmp directory so that they can just be there at startup rather than having to download them from somewhere else first?

Comment: No. But you can just bundle any files in your zip file, or, if they're too big, read from Cloud Storage.

Comment: Do these go away when the function is complete?  I have one function writing to /tmp and another trying to read from it, but the second one isn't finding the file

Comment: @sonicblis Each function executes in a different container and has its own isolated /tmp mount. Even subsequent calls to the same function will sometimes execute in a different container, so they'll have different /tmp mounts. So you can't use /tmp to communicate between functions. /tmp might be good for, for example, caching, or storing intermediate results from an external process.

Comment: @Trevor-dixon I'm doing the same thing, but using /tmp to create the file and cloud storage to store it for the next read.

Comment: Hi is there a way to grab a downloadable link of a file stored in tmp folder? or perhaps send the file back using http response in the same call?

Comment: @DaShaun, do you have the code for that ? Is there a limit to tmp size file we can write ? I'm running into the issue that my file is written in cloud function but is only 20 Bytes when it should be 1 Mo

Comment: @foufrix I think this is the relevant bits you need:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require('os');
const destFileName = '/tmp/timestamp';
const options = {
    destination: destFileName,
};
function writeValToFile(val) {
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(destFileName);
    writeStream.write('' + val + '');
    writeStream.end();
 }```

Comment: what is the maximum space that can be allocated in /tmp folder in case of gcp cloud function execution ?

Comment: what is the maximum space that can be allocated in /tmp folder in case of gcp cloud function execution ?

Comment: @PRUDHVICHOWDHARYNEKKALAPUDI 500 mb

Comment: @foufrix For how to move a file from container `/tmp` dir to the GCS bucket in Python runtime, see [Create new csv file in Google Cloud Storage from cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624213/11154841). Also explained in that answer: perhaps you can use `gcsfs` Python package instead and directly save and load from the GCS?

Comment: Is this outdated? The doc above now says `The filesystem itself is entirely writeable (except for files used by the underlying OS) and is stored within the Cloud Functions instance's memory.`

Comment: @Leonard  It appears the comment is still valid. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#memory-file-system