# Use Firebase Cloud Functions and Storage for searching?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720482/can-i-use-firebase-cloud-functions-for-search-engine) but I would like to extend my question based on the answers.

My goal is to implement something close to the [full text search solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) provided by the firebase documentation. While Algolia seems to be a great choice, it does not come cheap and introduces another third-party.

**Question:** I have the idea of building a search index based on Firestore data and save it as *JSON* in Cloud Storage. This *JSON* would be accessed by a Cloud Function that would use a library like [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) to execute a search (see the page for an example) and return it to a user.

Is this a reasonable thing to do for searching a collection with around 20000 documents / *JSON* size of around 3MB maximum?

Comment: It is definitely technically possible to do this, as I've answer to the question you linked. Whether it is "reasonable" is very subjective. If you have specific concerns, investigate those concerns. For example: my first concern would be about the performance of loading the file from Cloud Storage, so I'd test that performance first. If that performance is not good, I'd look at alternative storage locations for the JSON that may be faster.

Comment: impulse: it's a question of scale and tradeoffs. Building your own search index could certainly work. For a 3MB JSON document, it will probably work reasonably well. There are certainly some bits that could be made faster, though. Downloading and parsing a 3MB JSON document every time you want to run a search may be slower than you want, but if you only run a search infrequently, it could be fine. You also need to worry about how quickly you can update the index. A dedicated solution will likely perform better, but that doesn't really matter if you don't need better performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts on this Fred and Brandon. Our product will involve a lot of searches so performance and price is a major concern. Taking those points into consideration. hosting something like Elastic Search might be the better solution.