# Does Cloud Functions for Firebase support file operation?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a mobile app and it is using `Firebase` as the backend.
I want to compress some files immediately after they are uploaded to the [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) using [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).

So I need to write data to a temp file and after the compression is done I am going to upload the file to Cloud Storage.

Is this possible? Does Firebase Cloud Function support file operation?

Comment: what makes you suspect it isnt possible? nodejs supports it. show us what you tried and whats failing, else is too broad.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can write to /tmp in the instance where your function is running.  You can see an example of [image manipulation](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) with ImageMagick against a temporary file, along with [many other samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that are provided.

Comment: Can I write to `/tmp` while developing and testing local? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I can! Just found out thanks to your image manipulation example.