# Trying to do fs.writefile() inside an async cloud function (node v8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently building a cloud function to scrape some data from ecommerce websites. I'm running them on the Node.js v8 environment, so I'm able to use `async/await` without transpiling.

I need a way to save a file with the html response from the website so I can inspect it and decide how to best scrape it. And I haven't been able to make it work.

As I found resarching in many places, I need a way to promisify the `fs.writeFile()` function so that I can `await` for it. I've tried with `util.promisify` and also building the custom function below (both produce the same result, which is my cloud function crashing when I `await` for the result):

**index.js** (main file for the cloud functions - simplified version)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');

// PROMISIFY WRITEFILE TO SAVE URL RESPONSE
const promisifiedWriteFile = function(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile('./response.html', text, err => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
};

exports.getUrlProductDetails = functions.https.onCall(
  async (data) => {

    try {
      // SEND REQUEST TO URL PRODUCT PAGE, PARSE WITH CHEERIO
      response = await promisifiedRequest(productURL);
      $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

      // TRYING TO SAVE FILE
      await promisifiedWriteFile('12345'); // <----- THIS IS CRASHING
    } // TRY BLOCK - OUTER - END

    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Some internal error', err);
    }

  console.log('End of async function...');

  return {
    productDetails: productDetails,
    body: response.body // My client code is getting the body response just fine
  };
```

**Note1:** This is a simplified version of the code, but the single line that is crashing the function is: `await promisifiedWriteFile('12345');` and when I comment it out, everything else works just fine.

**Note2:** The file `response.html` gets created (with empty content), even with the function crashing at that point.

**Note3:** I should be trying to write the `response.body`. The `'12345'` is just for testing. But it crashes either way.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
// THIS IS WHAT LOGS OUT OF MY FUNCTION
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Execution took 2034 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

And this below is what my client gets: the error message is simply `internal`, because cloud functions avoid passing internal error details to the client.

[image]

**Note4:** I haven't deployed the function yet. This is all on local development.

Comment: Can you please share the error msg ?

Comment: share err you are getting and also use promisified fs method rather manually wrapping it https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api or use Promisifly from bluebird or use npm fs-extra

Comment: fs_promises_api is not available in Node 8

Comment: @Stanimirovv just added the error details.

Comment: @AZ_ just addedd the error details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to do it.

According to [this Firebase youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y), the `os.tmpdir()` **only one directory that is writable by your function's code.**

So did the following and now it works:

**index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();
const filePath = path.join(tmpdir,'response.html');

// PROMISIFY WRITEFILE TO SAVE URL RESPONSE
const promisifiedWriteFile = function(text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, text, err => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

And from inside the function I'm calling:

`await promisifiedWriteFile(response.body);`

Found some related doc also on this link:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec

Comment: "the os.tmpdir() only one directory that is writable". Highlighting this! You have saved my sanity!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're not allowed to write to the filesystem on Firebase functions. Try writing to `/tmp`, see [Does Cloud Functions for Firebase support file operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853853/does-cloud-functions-for-firebase-support-file-operation).

But I think you shouldn't be `writing` `response.html`, instead you should set the text and status code in the response that the Firebase function returns.

Comment: I'll check on that.