# How can I keep objects stored in firebase cloud function RAM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My application needs to build a couple of large hashmaps before processing a user's request. Ideally I want to store these hashmaps in-memory on the machine, which means it never has to do any expensive processing and can process any incoming requests quickly.

But this doesn't work for firebase because there's a chance a user triggers a new instance which sets off the very time-consuming preprocessing step.

So, I tried designing my application to use the firebase database, and get only the data it needs from the database each time instead of holding all the data in-memory. But, since the cloud functions are downloading loads of data from the database, I have now triggered over 1.7 GB in download for this month, just by myself from testing. This goes over the quota.

There must be something I'm missing; all I want is a permanent memory storage of some hashmaps. All I want is for those hashmaps to be ready by the time the function is called with a request. It seems like such a simple requirement; how come there is no way to do this?

Comment: You've asked the same question 3 different times in one day. I would suggest sticking with one question and update it and participate in comments as more data is revealed. To answer this question - if adding data to Firebase is causing your app to download a large amount of data each time, you may be doing it wrong. childAdded events are useful in these cases. That event presents just the newly added data to the app, which you can then integrate into your in-memory dataset. Voting to close as this is a redundant question.

Comment: Also, if you implement an observer using singleEvent, then your data will only be downloaded once and no more. Even if data is added, changed or removed from Firebase, the app will not receive an event until the next time it's run and the singleEvent is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store data in the container that runs your Cloud Functions, you can use [its local tempfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function), which is actually kept in memory. But this will disappear when the container is recycled, which happens when your function hasn't been access for a while. So this local file system will have to be rebuilt whenever the container spins up.

If you want permanent storage of values you generate, consider using Google Cloud Storage. It is probably a more cost effective option, and definitively the most scalable one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try using cloud storage actually, I used it to house a bunch of csvs I would read into the /tmp dir and then turn them into hashmaps. The problem was as you mentioned when the container is reset it has to do it all over again right? I don't see how this is avoided with cloud storage since I still have to read the data into the server to process it into hashmaps.

Comment: I finally realized, the reason my code was so slow was that it was running outside the cloud function before it's declared (I have no idea why that makes it go slow). Once I put it in the cloud function it runs very quickly. The problem is, if I have to re-download the whole database at every request just to build the hashmaps, it is a very unsustainable solution because I will run out of storage bandwidth very quickly. Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. I can't comment on any better way without seeing the code that reproduces the problem. That's why I only explained how the system works.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have minimal code because my question is more about why I need to incur quotas for such a simple need. Another clarification: the reason I think my request should be very reasonable, is I could accomplish it by literally declaring the entire 80 MB of hashmaps data in the code. Maybe I'll write a script that enumerates all those fields in js and put it inside the index.js itself? Then it never has to download from anywhere, and won't incur any quotas. However this seems like a very desperate solution for what seems to be a simple problem.