# How come when I put file downloading/processing code outside of a firebase function it runs extremely slowly?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my Firebase Cloud functions I need to keep some large hashmaps in memory to aid in processing incoming requests. I tried to do this by having some code before the cloud functions are actually declared, which downloads the files from firebase storage, processes them and turns them into hashmaps. But this runs extremely slowly (takes 10 minutes just to download 10 MB).

I figured out that if I put it in a cloud function it will run quickly. However, this means I'd have to download the whole database every request which would make my bandwidth run out extremely quickly.

Maybe I should try having it as a global variable and the cloud function will only populate it if it needs to?

Comment: There are many reasons why this might happen, some controllable, others not. There is no way to help without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the same/similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856676/how-can-i-keep-objects-stored-in-firebase-cloud-function-ram) please see the answer to that question.