# What is the best way to store a large constant hashmap in node.js (firebase cloud functions)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

If I try to download or read the file from Firebase database or firebase storage, it will incur unnecessarily large quota costs and be financially unsustainable. And since firebase only has an in-memory file system with a "tmp" directory it is impossible to deploy any files there.

The reason I think my request should be very reasonable, is I could accomplish it by literally declaring the entire 80 MB of hashmaps data in the code. Maybe I'll write a script that enumerates all those fields in js and put it inside the index.js itself? Then it never has to download from anywhere, and won't incur any quotas. However this seems like a very desperate solution for what seems to be a simple problem.

Cross post of https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-keep-objects-stored-in-RAM-with-Cloud-Functions

Comment: What is in that 80MB of data? You should explore ways to segment or partition the data so you can download only what you need. By the way, why do you think that `index.js` won't have to be downloaded?

Comment: Are you cross-posting from here? Quora is a better forum for open-ended questions like this. But if you do need to cross-post, please say that you are doing so.  https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-keep-objects-stored-in-RAM-with-Cloud-Functions

Comment: torazaburo even if I download only what I need per request, it is still too much and will rapidly drain my database quota. The index.js file already lives in the server that needs to do the processing; no one needs to download it.

Comment: This is the same/similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856676/how-can-i-keep-objects-stored-in-firebase-cloud-function-ram) please see the answer to that question.