# How to fix "No Such File or Directory" in /tmp folder in Google Cloud Functions - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I need to save a file to the tmp folder within Google Cloud Functions. I am accessing the file from Google Cloud Storage and then sending it to Cloud Functions to process the file. It is an MP4 file so I cannot use any of the functions available for text only files.

I believe my only two options are to either retrieve the binary of the file, which I could not find documented anywhere, or save the file to the tmp folder but this tmp folder which runs in memory. I cannot find much documentation on this however.

The best I have found is: [tmp file in Google cloud Functions for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487885/tmp-file-in-google-cloud-functions-for-python), however as I am not working with a text file I could not get this to work.

I am constantly getting an error that the file or directory does not exist.

My code looks like the following (nearly identical to [tmp file in Google cloud Functions for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487885/tmp-file-in-google-cloud-functions-for-python))

```py
def function(file):
    name = uploadedFile['name']
    path_name = get_file_path(name)


def get_file_path(file_name):
    return os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), file_name)
```

I removed a few lines that were text file specific.

I am not sure if I have to manually enable the tmp/ folder or if there is some other way I can fix this but whenever I run the function and provide the file, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/filename.mp4'`

I am assuming that 1 of 2 things are happening, 1) next line of code is executing before the file is done running being copied (running asynchronously), or 2 there is something I have to do to enable and be able to write to the tmp folder.

Thanks.

Comment: does `/tmp` exist already?

Comment: @FamousAv8er I believe it already is as I cannot find any documentation to the contrary and cannot find any documentation that would allow me to enable it.

Comment: The directory exists, it's in memory directory. But,before reading the file, are you writing it? Where this part of the code ? do you have issue when writing file to /tmp/ ?

Comment: Can you include the code where you are you actually reading/writing the file?

Answer (score 2):

First is to retrieve the file from Google cloud storage as a blob and convert and download to `/tmp`. You will need `google.cloud` import storage, which requires both `google-cloud` and `google-cloud-storage` in your `requirements.txt` file.

```
bucket_name = "bucket-name"
source_blob_name = "audio-file.wav"
destination_file_name = "/tmp/audio-file.wav

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

Now you just need to read from the `/tmp` folder. In my case it is an audio file so I am using `scipy`:

```
scipy.io.wavfile.read('/tmp/audio-file.wav')
```

I think the documentation from Google is a little misleading on this as it doesn't actually require any use of `os.path` at all.

ref: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#functions-concepts-filesystem-python

You can also pass static files into `/tmp` using a ZIP if the folder structure matches. You wont however see this tmp folder anywhere in the console, but it is there.