# Using TfidfVectorizer with Punkt in Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, nltk, tmp, tfidfvectorizer

My current understanding of `TfidfVectorizer` is it requires `nltk.download("punkt")` to be run before transformation on input data, as all the default tokenizers are available in `punkt`. Currently, because I use `TfidfVectorizer` in my Cloud Function, I run `nltk.download("punkt")` inside of the Cloud Function container, which downloads `punkt` to `/tmp`. My issue with this is that I can't guarantee access to the same file system contents for each invocation of my Google Cloud Function because "subsequent calls to the same function will sometimes execute in a different container, so they'll have different `/tmp` mounts. So you can't use `/tmp` to communicate between functions" (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function)). This leads to `punkt` needing to be redownloaded anytime the container is switched, and this shows up in the logs of my Cloud Function.

I tried creating a tokenizer deserialized from `english.pickle` that is part of `punkt`. Even when passing in this custom tokenizer's `tokenize` function as `tokenizer` to `TfidVectorizer`, the transformation of input data later on ends up failing because of the missing `punkt` download.

Is there anyway to download `punkt` into Python's available memory, such that it doesn't get stored in the file system and get wiped when the container is switched? It seems like I need `punkt` to be downloaded into the file system regardless of whether I pass in a custom tokenizer or let `TfidfVectorizer` choose its own default tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly download files to /tmp and expect to see them there for future function invocations *that use the same server instance*.  You just don't have a guarantee which server instance is going to be used to handle any given event.  Server instances will be reused as Cloud Functions sees fit, but it can also deallocate a server instance without warning.

But what you can do is simply check to see if the file you want is already present from a prior execution before doing anything.  If the file is present, no download needed - just use the file.  If not present, then perform the download.