# How to use localStorage in firebas cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to use the web storage API in my cloud function?
I need to set/get auth token in localStorage for a 3rd party service.

I'm watching for updates to a document, based on the update I need to call a 3rd party service, but the 3rd party service auths with bearer tokens. My question is can I use localStorage to set/get this token?

Comment: I think you really need to add more detail to your question. I prefer to use the python library to work with `storage`. But your question is not clear enough on what you want.

Comment: Hi @Racu, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions run on a server, so don't have access to a browser-based `localStorage` implementation.

If you want to store something on the server, you can write it to the [temporary file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function). Just be aware that this can disappear at any moment and is not persisted, so you should only use it for caches you can also recalculate.

If you want to store data persistently, you should use a persistent storage layer, typically a cloud based database of some sort (such as Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore).