# Temp folder for google cloud functions not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Hi all I am trying to download an audio file from telegram and parse into google cloud functions temp folder for processing. I am trying to do some transcribing from an audio file.

However, it keeps throwing an error at line `ft.transcode(voice.download('/tmp/file.ogg'), 'wav')` saying that the file does not exist. Does GCF have a tmp folder?

My code is as below

```
import os
import telegram
import speech_recognition as sr
import ftransc.core as ft
from googletrans import Translator
from google.cloud import speech_v1


bot = telegram.Bot(token=os.environ["TELEGRAM_TOKEN"])
translator = Translator()

def webhook(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
        chat_id = update.message.chat.id
        # Reply with the same message
        # getting the audio  file 
        audio_data = update.message.voice
        chat_data = update.message.text

        if audio_data  :

            voice = bot.getFile(audio_data.file_id)    
            print ("hello")
            print(voice)
            voice.download('/tmp/file.ogg')
            os.listdir('/tmp')
            ft.transcode(voice.download('/tmp/file.ogg'), 'wav')
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.WavFile('/tmp/file.wav') as source:
                audio = r.record(source)
                txt = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(txt) 

        else :
            print(chat_data)
            try:

                translated = translator.translate(chat_data, dest='bn')
                transldated_data = translated.text
            except :
                transldated_data = "please try again"
            print(transldated_data)
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=transldated_data)
    return "ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a tmp folder, ‘/tmp’[1].

Be wary when using the /tmp to store files, especially if you are attempting to use it as a relatively permanent storage for files you need access to often. As mentioned by another Googler[2], each function executes in its own container with its own /tmp directory. Even multiple calls to the same function can execute in different containers therefore having different /tmp mounts.

If a more permanent storage is required, a recommendation would be to use Cloud Storage[3] to store the audio files for later use. You may then download the audio files accordingly whenever you have a need for them.

This can also be achieved through implementing Cloud Storage triggers for your function[4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system

[2] [Write temporary files from Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function)

[3] https://cloud.google.com/storage

[4] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage