# Create new csv file in Google Cloud Storage from cloud function

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

First time working with Google Cloud Storage. Below I have a cloud function which is triggered whenever a csv file gets uploaded to `my-folder` inside my bucket. My goal is to create a new csv file in the same folder, read the contents of the uploaded csv and convert each line to a URL that will go into the newly created csv. Problem is I'm having trouble just *creating* the new csv in the first place, let alone actually writing to it.

My code:

```
import os.path
import csv
import sys
import json
from csv import reader, DictReader, DictWriter
from google.cloud import storage
from io import StringIO

def generate_urls(data, context):
    if context.event_type == 'google.storage.object.finalize':
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket_name = data['bucket']
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        folder_name = 'my-folder'
        file_name = data['name']

        if not file_name.endswith('.csv'):
            return
```

These next few lines came from [an example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/storage_compose_file.py) in GCP's GitHub repo. This is when I would expect the new csv to be created, but nothing happens.

```
        # Prepend 'URL_' to the uploaded file name for the name of the new csv
        destination = bucket.blob(bucket_name + '/' + file_name[:14] + 'URL_' + file_name[14:])
        destination.content_type = 'text/csv'
        sources = [bucket.get_blob(file_name)]
        destination.compose(sources)
        output = bucket_name + '/' + file_name[:14] + 'URL_' + file_name[14:]


        # Transform uploaded csv to string - this was recommended on a similar SO post, not sure if this works or is the right approach...
        blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
        blob = blob.download_as_string()
        blob = blob.decode('utf-8')
        blob = StringIO(blob)

        input_csv = csv.reader(blob)
```

On the next line is where I get an error: `No such file or directory: 'myProjectId/my-folder/URL_my_file.csv'`

```
        with open(output, 'w') as output_csv:
            csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(input_csv, )
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_csv, fieldnames=['URL'], delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_dict_reader:
                line_count += 1
                url = ''
                ...
                # code that converts each line
                ...
                csv_writer.writerow({'URL': url})
            print(f'Total rows: {line_count}')
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could get this to create the new csv and then write to it, it would be a huge help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably I would say that I have a few questions about the code and the design of the solution:

1. As I understand - on one hand the cloud function is triggered by a `finalise` event [Google Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), not he other hand you would like to save a newly created file into the same bucket. Upon success, an appearance of a new object in that bucket is to trigger another instance of your cloud function. Is that the intended behaviour? You cloud function is ready for that?
2. Ontologically there is no such thing as `folder`. Thus in this code:

```
        folder_name = 'my-folder'
        file_name = data['name']
```

the first line is a bit redundant, unless you would like to use that variable and value for something else... and the `file_name` gets the object name including all prefixes (you may consider them as "folders".

3. The example you refer - [storage_compose_file.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/storage_compose_file.py) - is about how a few objects in the GCS can be composed into one. I am not sure if that example is relevant for your case, unless you have some additional requirements.
4. Now, let's have a look at this snippet:

```
        destination = bucket.blob(bucket_name + '/' + file_name[:14] + 'URL_' + file_name[14:])
        destination.content_type = 'text/csv'
        sources = [bucket.get_blob(file_name)]
        destination.compose(sources)
```

a. `bucket.blob` - is a factory constructor - see [API buckets description](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html). I am not sure if you really would like to use a `bucket_name` as an element of its argument...

b. `sources` - becomes a list with only one element - a reference to the  existing object in the GCS bucket.

c. `destination.compose(sources)` - is it an attempt to make a copy of the existing object? If successful - it may trigger another instance of your cloud function.

5. About type changes

```
        blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
        blob = blob.download_as_string()
```

After the first line the `blob` variable has the type `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob`. After the second - `bytes`. I think Python allows such things... but would you really like it? BTW, the `download_as_string` method is deprecated - see [Blobs / Objects API](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)

6. About the `output`:

```
   output = bucket_name + '/' + file_name[:14] + 'URL_' + file_name[14:]
    
   with open(output, 'w') as output_csv:
```

Bear in mind - all of that happens inside the memory of the cloud function. Nothing to do with the GCS buckets of blobs. If you would like to use temporary files within cloud functions - you are to use them in the `/tmp` directory - [Write temporary files from Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function) I would guess that you get the error because of this issue.

=> Coming to some suggestions.

You probably would like to download the object into the cloud function memory (into the `/tmp` directory). Then you would like to process the source file and save the result near the source. Then you would like to upload the result to *another* (not the source) bucket. If my assumptions are correct, I would suggest to implement those things step by step, and check that you get the desired result on each step.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Regarding point #2, I'm using `folder_name` and `file_name` in some conditional checks that I didn't include here to keep the question more concise. One condition avoids processing new files that include 'URL_' so that the function doesn't get triggered in a loop. I can see now where I was getting confused. I'll try your suggestion and create a new file in `/tmp` and write to it there. I assume it's possible then to move the new file from `/tmp` to `my-folder` after I've written to it?

Comment: It might work. Pay attention to cloud function timeouts, maximum allocated memory (those temp files eat the allocated memory), IAM permissions to write objects into GCS buckets (the service account under which the cloud function is running should have relevant permissions. Bear in mind that you pay for time, thus saving the result file into the original bucket - you waste you money.

Comment: So I was able to create the new csv in the `/tmp` directory, but now I'm getting errors trying to move it into my bucket's folder. Posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413379/move-file-from-tmp-folder-to-google-cloud-storage-bucket

Answer (score 2):

You can reach saving a csv in the Google Cloud Storage in two ways.

Either, you save it directly to GCS with `gcsfs` package in the "requirements.txt", or you use the container's `/tmp` folder and push it to the GCS bucket afterwards from there.

## Use the power of the Python package "gcsfs"

`gcsfs` stands for "Google Cloud Storage File System". Add

```
gcsfs==2021.11.1
```

or another version to your "requirements.txt". You do not directly use this package name in the code, instead, its installation just allows you to save to the Google Cloud Storage directly, no interim `/tmp` and push to GCS bucket directory needed. You can also store the file in a sub-directory.

You can save a dataframe for example with:

```py
df.to_csv('gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/MY_OUTPUT.csv')
```

or:

```py
df.to_csv('gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/MY_DIR/MY_OUTPUT.csv')
```

or use an environment variable of the first menu step when creating the CF:

```py
from os import environ

df.to_csv(environ["CSV_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH"], index=False)
```

Not sure whether this is needed, but I saw an example where the gcsfs package is installed together with

```
fsspec==2021.11.1
```

and it will not hurt adding it. My tests of saving a small df to csv on GCS did not need the package, though. Since I am not sure about this helping module, quote:

> [Purpose](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) (of fsspec):
>
> To produce a template or specification for a file-system interface,
> that specific implementations should follow, so that applications
> making use of them can rely on a common behaviour and not have to
> worry about the specific internal implementation decisions with any
> given backend. Many such implementations are included in this package,
> or in sister projects such as s3fs and gcsfs.
>
> In addition, if this is well-designed, then additional functionality,
> such as a key-value store or FUSE mounting of the file-system
> implementation may be available for all implementations "for free".

## First in container's "/tmp", then push to GCS

Here is an example of how to do [what the other answer says about storing it at first in the container's `/tmp` (and *only* there, no other dir is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function)) and then moving it to a bucket of your choice. You can also save it to the bucket that also stores the source code of the cloud function, against the last sentence of the other answer (tested, works):

```py
# function `write_to_csv_file()` not used but might be helpful if no df at hand:
#def write_to_csv_file(file_path, file_content, root):
#    """ Creates a file on runtime. """
#    file_path = path.join(root, file_path)
#
#    # If file is a binary, we rather use 'wb' instead of 'w'
#    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
#        file.write(file_content)    

def push_to_gcs(file, bucket):
    """ Writes to Google Cloud Storage. """
    file_name = file.split('/')[-1]
    print(f"Pushing {file_name} to GCS...")
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(file)
    print(f"File pushed to {blob.id} succesfully.")        

# Root path on CF will be /workspace, while on local Windows: C:\
root = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
file_name = 'test_export.csv'
# This is the main step: you *must* use `/tmp`:
file_path = '/tmp/' + file_name

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv(path.join(root, file_path), index = False)

# If you have a df anyway, `df.to_csv()` is easier. 
# The following file writer should rather be used if you have records instead (here: dfAsString). Since we do not use the function `write_to_csv_file()`, it is also commented out above, but can be useful if no df at hand.
# dfAsString = df.to_string(header=True, index=False)   
# write_to_csv_file(file_path, dfAsString, root)

# Cloud Storage Client
# Move csv file to Cloud Storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = MY_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
push_to_gcs(path.join(root, file_path), bucket)
```