# Setting download directory to Cloud Storage in chrome-drive in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function that access to a website and download CSV file to Cloud Storage.

I managed to access the site using headless-chrominium and chromedriver. 
On my local environment I can set up the download directory like below

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": download_dir,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
})
```

where `download_dir` is like `"/usr/USERID/tmp/"`

How in Cloud Function could I assigned the value so that it points to the right Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, a GCS bucket cannot be mounted as a local drive in runtime environment used for cloud functions.

Thus, you might need to download the source `csv` file into the cloud function memory and save it, for example, as [a file in the "/tmp" directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function).

Then, you can upload it from that location into a GCS bucket. A more detailed explanation how to upload - is provided here: [Move file from /tmp folder to Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413379/move-file-from-tmp-folder-to-google-cloud-storage-bucket/69415386#69415386)

Note: cloud functions have some restrictions - i.e. memory and timeout. Make sure that you allocated (during deployment) enough memory and time to process your `csv` files.

In addition, make sure that a service account, which is used by your cloud function, has relevant IAM roles for the GCS bucket under discussion.